# while creating a new Spring Starter Project in STS, I am getting error, "loader constraint violation: loader "

Tags: spring

I am new to Spring n coding, I am trying to develop a practice code Project of spring, but while creating spring Starter Project, I am getting following error even though i did not add any dependency, I keep getting the same error.

the error log reads.
"An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project".
loader constraint violation: loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @3d9b7171 wants to load class org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject. A different class with the same name was previously loaded by org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @1f96d661. (org.apache.maven.project.MavenProject is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @1f96d661, parent loader 'platform')"

i tried to search the solution, but couldn't find much helpful,  i have some previously created spring starter projects on sts which are working fine.